# Adding Data to X509 certificate

Tags: java, ssl, ldap, certificate

I have an user certificate field in LDAP, which accepts X509 certificate.
I have created an X509 certificate following the user guides available at bouncy castle wiki.

The cerficate is created successfully and is added to LDAP. My requirement is that i have an ecrypted data for each user, which i need to save to the user certificate field.

How can i add this data to the user certificate?

I have created a Version 1  User certificate using the below code.

```
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

            KeyPairGenerator kpGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "BC");
            kpGen.initialize(1024, new SecureRandom());
            KeyPair pair = kpGen.generateKeyPair();

            X509v1CertificateBuilder certBldr = new JcaX509v1CertificateBuilder(
                    new X500Name("CN=User Certificate:"),
                    BigInteger.valueOf(1),
                    new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()),
                    new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + (5*365*24*60*60*1000)),
                    new X500Name("CN=User Certificate:"),
                    pair.getPublic());
                    ContentSigner signer = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA1withRSA")
                    .setProvider("BC").build(pair.getPrivate());

                cert= new JcaX509CertificateConverter().setProvider("BC")
                .getCertificate(certBldr.build(signer));
```

Answer (score 1):

> The cerficate is created successfully and is added to LDAP. My requirement is that i have an ecrypted data for each user, which i need to save to the user certificate field.

Something wrong there. The `userCertificate` attribute is for an X.509 certificate. Putting anything else in there would be an LDAP schema violation.

> How can i add this data to the user certificate?

You can't.

Comment: Ok . thanks for the reply. can i use the data for the user while creating the user certificate? i need to get the data back again and use it later. Like add to some custom fileds while generating the certificate? Certificate browser in apache studio shows custom fields, like X500 name (ou, o, cn etc)

Comment: You can supply any data that `keytool` asks for when creating a private key. Or whatever `openssl.exe` asks for. Once the certificate is created, you can't change it.